# VideoJS: Where is current information on supported video formats and their browser and platform compatibility?

Tags: video.js

Since the site reorg, I'm unable to find current information on supported video formats and their browser and platform compatibility. There's no search I can find on the videojs.com site, support links to SO, docs to the github readme, and far as I can see, none of those have this basic info. I'm probably just being thick, since that's such fundamental info, but please tell me, where is that info?

Answer (score 11):

They themselves don't support video formats, with HTML5 video the browser does all the work and when it falls back to flash player, then it's any format that flash supports.

For the HTML5 Support see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#Browser_support):

For Flash Support see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_Video#Media_type_support):

Answer (score 2):

As another answer mentioned, the VideoJs library itself is **format-agnostic**. However there is a blogpost a year or so ago by Brightcove that spells out best practice for picking video formats with videojs (and by extension html video in general).

The post gives a breakdown of browser support. By far your best starting point is to use **MP4 with H.264 baseline video encoding and AAC audio**. To increase browser support you then might consider throwing in WebM, OGG and/or 3GP formats as fallbacks.

The full post is here:
http://blog.zencoder.com/2013/09/13/what-formats-do-i-need-for-html5-video/