# Video file types for videojs

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, video.js

I'm building an app that uses videojs for playing videos. What types of files do I need for playing videos.  Now I have h264 in a mp4 container.

Do I need also different encodings/containers?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the referenced article here:

[VideoJS: Where is current information on supported video formats and their browser and platform compatibility?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16872721/videojs-where-is-current-information-on-supported-video-formats-and-their-brows)

You are probably safe with just h.264 and webm. Add ogv if you want to support ancient versions of Firefox (3.5/3.6).